# How do I correct this error from using genetic algorithm and LSTM

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, genetic-algorithm

Here is my code

```
#hence train the model with the optimal number of lstm units and optimal window size for prediction
X_train,y_train = prepare_dataset(train_data,optimal_window_size)
X_test, y_test = prepare_dataset(test_data,optimal_window_size)

inputs = Input(shape=(optimal_window_size,1))
x = LSTM(optimal_num_units, input_shape=(optimal_window_size,1))(inputs)
predictions = Dense(1, activation='relu')(x)
model = Model(inputs = inputs, outputs = predictions)
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='mean_squared_error')
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=1, batch_size=20,shuffle=True)
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)

rmse = np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred))
print('Test RMSE: ', rmse)
```

I get this error:

```
ValueError: Unexpected result of `predict_function` (Empty batch_outputs). Please use `Model.compile(..., run_eagerly=True)`, or `tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)` for more information of where went wrong, or file a issue/bug to `tf.keras`.
```

Comment: Please provide some more code like the shape of `train_data` and `test_data` or how `prepare_dataset()` is defined, to understand and fix this error.

Comment: data = pd.read_csv('pv_data_date_mono.csv')
data = np.reshape(np.array(data['pv_output']),(len(data['pv_output']),1))

train_data = data[:-365]
test_data = data[-365:]